# Model of Quintessential Inflation

Tags: cosmology, field-theory, potential-energy, cosmological-inflation, cosmological-constant

I have a question about how the potential for an inflaton field is selected. It is clear that there are limitations associated with number of e-folds, scalar-to-tensor relation and scalar spectral index. But are there any other requirements from quantum field theory? Let's say I want to offer the following potential, which satisfies the requirements listed above and looks like this: $$V(\varphi)=V_0\exp{(-ne^{\alpha \varphi})}+\Lambda,$$ where $\Lambda$ - cosmological constant. But this is just a potential for which satisfactory parameters can be selected. It does not follow from any action from quantum field theory. Is there any special need to justify the choice of such a potential? Is there any way to justify it?